# Convert Base64Binary to PDF using PHP

Tags: php

I tried lots of script which is available in internet to decode my Base64Binary to PDF they not working. Please help me.

[Here is the sample encoded PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzfpIyvhShqNNFVnZUZFdFEwbEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried `file_put_contents('whatever.pdf', file_get_contents('whatever.extHere'))`?

Comment: yes, now i tried your code also it's not working

Comment: Is this binary data that PDF understands? Did you change `'whatever.extHere'` to `'sample.txt'`?

Comment: awesome i got answer!. what i did is, i encode the Base64Binary and decode it to Base64.

$data = base64_encode($contents);
file_put_contents($item_id . '.pdf', base64_decode($data));

Comment: thanks for your answers @PHPglue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = base64_encode($contents);
file_put_contents('output.pdf', base64_decode($data));
```